# Is this grow light (GE BR30) harmful to your eyes?

Tags: indoors, light, safety

Can the GE BR30 LED grow light could pose harm to one's eyes, especially if they are used in somewhere like a high bedroom shelf where the bulb itself is visible from below?

[image: GE BR30 Grow Light]

Here is an image of the light's spectrum. As you can see, it goes somewhat low on the blue spectrum:

[image: Image of light spectrum/normalized photon flux]

[image: PPF]

Obviously, I am not staring up at the lights, but I have five of these on a high shelf in my bedroom. The lights are visible in the background when I am looking at my plants.

The lights are full-spectrum and appear to have some light emissions under 450 nm

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the light has no emissions in the non-visible spectrum, then it emits no ultraviolet light, so there is no danger from UV radiation. The fact that it's weighted heavier to the red than the blue wavelengths is also a good sign, as there is evidence that too much blue light can damage your retinas (BTW, if you haven't adjusted your laptop and phone to the red [default nighttime] setting full time, you should).

[Here](https://medicgrow.com/blogs/news/are-led-grow-lights-harmful-to-humans) is a blog post that seems to have pretty decent information on this topic.

If you were using this in, say, a basement grow setup where you're only occasionally in its proximity, then I think you'd be fine. But given what you've told us about your setup, you should ask an opthamologist or optician for their opinion.